# CSS position: fixed

Tags: css, html

I have `position:fixed` `<div>` that appears in the middle of the screen.  When there are messages, a second `position:fixed` `<div>` is put next to the first `<div>`.

I'm finding on different screen sizes (say a netbook - small screen) the `<div>`'s sit on top of each other.

Is there a way to lock their position to each other? I tried using a fixed container to hold both of them, but they still moved.

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS - container1 and container2 still move when I change the screen size.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: fixed
}
#container1 {
  position: fixed
}
#container2 {
  position: fixed
}
```

do I need to use relative positioning on the container 1/2 divs?

Comment: You aren't revealing very much by withholding your CSS code.

Comment: Regarding comments made within your follow-up edit, see my full answer below regarding size and position.  Also, again, what is your CSS code?  I know you're still withholding it because simply putting `position:fixed` by itself will not center something on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most importantly, `id` is **unique**.  You cannot use `id="container"` on three different elements.  Each must have their own `id`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Should be something like this...

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
</div>
```

Also, where is your CSS code?

If you don't want these things to push each other around as the window size changes, one  method would be to specify the exact size and position of each container.

**EDIT:**

Again, without seeing an example of this page, a demo, or a better description of what you want, this is speculation.

You could put fixed position on the wrapper and then put an exact size and position on the `<div>`'s within.

Answer (score 1):

The `position: fixed` CSS rule "fixes" the element's position on the screen. Once you set it to `fixed`, it will never move from the position you put it in. Since you're applying `fixed` to all of your elements, you're seeing the elements stack (likely in the top-left of your screen considering you're not providing a top or left value).

If you want the child elements to appear inside your fixed container, just don't add `position: fixed` to them and they'll sit inside the parent just fine.

Of course, all of this is pure speculation considering we can't see an example of your problem, nor your desired result.

Comment: If the OP wants fixed positioning (fixed relative to viewport), then using a combination of relative and absolute will do him no good.  I agree, this is all speculation without more information.

Comment: Indeed. Solving problems when the actual problem and the desired outcome are unknowns is kind of impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant fix the position of your div like this. first of all you have to find the screen size for your parent div which contains that div u want in middle.like

```
<div id="parent"> <div id="middle_div"></div> </div>
function getScreenSize()
{
        var winW, winH;
        winW = document.getElementById('parent').availWidth;
        winh = document.getElementById('parent').availHeight;
   }
```

this is how you vil get the size availabel for parent div.Then set the width and height of parent div according to it.now if you have width of parent div its easy to set middle_div in middle of parent div.

Comment: It's assumed that he's simply neglecting to reveal all his code.  Surely he doesn't need to know how to center something when he's already telling you it's being fixed and centered.

Comment: @sparky: i have just given him idea of how can he get the size of parent div for small screens.According to  that he can fix the size of those two div dynamically...

Comment: You've provided a specific answer for a yet unknown problem since we can't see his actual code and don't even really know what he wants.